# Sprintf flags and width - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to understand how `sprintf` works.

Looking at the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) here's the format/syntax `%[flags][width][.precision]type`

I tried to understand my code here:

```
format('%02.2f', monthly_payment)
```

focusing on `%02.2f` I understand that .2f means round it to two decimal float but what does `%02` means?

Breaking it down like this:

- 0 - flag
- 2 - width
- 2- precision
- f - type

Can anyone explain this in a layman's term and give examples (to better understand this concept) that I can try out on irb?

Comment: Search for "pad with zeroes" and "examples of width" at [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) .

Comment: I did but no specific info about this. Hopefully you could help me.

Comment: @Max's answer should clarify things for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%02.2f`

has these parts:

- `02` is split into two parts:

  - `0` is the flag
  - `2` is the minimum width
- `.2`: precision (amount of zeros)
- `f`: type (float)

The difference between `%2.0` and `%02.0` is the flag. If it's given, then the minimum width will be enforced by left-padding zeros. Otherwise, whitespace will be left-padded.

You can right-pad instead by using a `-`.

Note that the minimum-width will include the decimal space if there is one.

To give some example with the string `'1'`:

```
format('%2f', "1")
=> "1.000000"
# Here I'm only specifying that the length is 'at least 2'.

format('%2.0f', "1")
=> " 1"
# min-width of 2, precision of zero, and padding with whitespace

format('%.2f', "1")
=> "1.00"
# just set precision, don't set min-width

format('%02.0f', "1")
=> "01"
# min-width of 2, precision of zero, and padding with zeroes

format('%-2.0f', "1")
=> "1 "
# using a dash to right pad

format('%-02.0f', "1")
=> "1 "
# when '-' is used the 0 flag will still pad with whitespace

format('%2.2f', "1")
=> "1.00"
# min-width of 2 and precision of 2

format('%5.2f', "1")
=> "01.00"
# min-width of 5, precision of 2, padding with whitespace
```